# Golang build cannot find module for path _/mnt/c/XXXXX

Tags: go, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My system is WSL 2 in Windows 10.

```sh
 OS: Debian 10 buster
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.104-microsoft-standard
 Shell: zsh 5.7.1
 CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 4900HS with Radeon Graphics @ 16x 2.994GHz
```

Golang info:

```sh
go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOPATH="/mnt/c/workspace/6.824"
```

And I met a problem when I build a project by plugin model:

```sh
$ go build -buildmode=plugin ../mrapps/wc.go
build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path _/mnt/c/workspace/6.824/src/mr
```

It is so strange that "_/mnt"

How can I solve it?
Why has a "_" before the path?

Help me, please.

Answer (score 2):

I would try and use [`go mod`](https://golang.org/ref/mod) instead of relying on `GOPATH`

```
unset GOPATH
cd /mnt/c/workspace/6.824/
go mod init "yourProject"
go build -buildmode=plugin mrapps/wc.go
```

Comment: First, thank you for this answer.

but I tried follow your command, and it does not work out.

I had used docker to solve this problem.

But I still want to know the reason for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using go mod. And you can try the following command to fix:

```
cd 6.824
go mod init "6.824-golabs-2020" 
# change file src/mrapps/wc.go line9 to `import "6.824-golabs-2020/src/mr"`
cd src
go build -buildmode=plugin mrapps/wc.go
```

More details about mod you can refer to https://golang.org/ref/mod